# Java : How to check if a key is exists in a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have defined a hashmap of type :

```
HashMap<Position, Double> list = new HashMap<>();
```

Where Position is class with two attributes x and y .

I would like to verify if a position is already in the list or not, I have tried this :

```
public void addToList(Position p, double somme) {
    if (this.list.containsKey(p)) {
        this.list.replace(p, this.list.get(p) + somme);//add the old value somme 
    } else {
        this.list.put(p, somme);
    }
}
```

I think I should be more specific and verify values of x any y instead of check if key is exist because each time the check failed to detect an exist position.

How can check if a position is in the list or not?

Comment: What does `Position.equals` check? Would this not already be checking the x and y?

Comment: (Don't call a variable of type HashMap "list". That's just confusing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your Position object so that two elements with the same value for x and y are equals.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Position otherPos = (Position) obj;
    return x == otherPos.x
            && y == otherPos.y;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y);
}
```

Comment: You also need `hashCode` for that, not just `equals`.

Comment: I still have a problem when i use list.put  and  hashCode(), i want to add to the list  points even with same (x,y). for example (2,3) and (2,3).it is possible only if i disable  hashCode().

Comment: Your list variable is a HashMap. HashMap can not store duplicated keys, they automatically do what you asked for (if the key exists the last value is stored) so to update the value you just need to put the new value to that same key. You might want to create another more specific question if you want something different now

Comment: If you need to store different values to the same key in a hashmap, which doesn't seem to be the case according to the question, check this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys

Comment: I have followed the instructions and when  i tried to implement :---> protected Multimap<Position, Double>  donneeTraitee = TreeMultimap.create();, i got this error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeMultimap<Comparable,Comparable> to Multimap<Position,Double> i changed  it and then i have got this warning : Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized

Comment: But why do you want now to implement a MultiMap? You can achieve what you wanted with a HashMap, check this code:  http://tpcg.io/j0BZEUZ7 If it finds the element it updates the value (with the sum of the old value and the new one) if not just puts the element, is exactly what you asked for in the question. I don't see the need to store duplicated keys now

Answer (score 3):

Implement both equals AND hashcode in your Position class, based on the x and y properties. Hashmap uses the latter to find the bucket in which to check for the key - equals alone won't work.

Note that hashcode and equals must be consistent in that two objects that are equal must have the same hashcode.

As the other answer mentioned, implement those and containsKey method based on a Position will work as you expect.